# Wowza streaming engine Eclipse server.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, wowza

I'm trying to start programming with WSE with Eclipse (Server Side API), but when I try to build my java program I get the following error:

`ERROR: Server.xml not found: exiting.`

Here is the image: 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QoIA.png

I have installed the Wowza Streaming Engine. 4.3.0 and it is running (I started manually through `services.msc`). Afterwards, I tried to find some useful tutorials but I couldn't understand them exactly.

Here is my landscape

- Eclipse with Wowza Addon: OK
- Wowza Streaming Engine installed: OK
- Running Wowza Streaming Engine: OK

What exactly should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error but on Mac. it's worked for me, but i don't know about Windows.

You need to change Run configuration in Eclipse. Go to **Eclipse -> Run -> Run configurations**. Choice **WowzaStreamingEngine_project** and go to the **Arguments** tab. You need to add following lines in **VM arguments** section:

> -Dcom.wowza.wms.ConfigHome=/**path/to/your**/WowzaStreamingEngine 
>   -Dcom.wowza.wms.AppHome=/**path/to/your**/WowzaStreamingEngine 
>   -XX:+UseG1GC 
>   -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100

I took this options on start Wowza server without Eclipse

Maybe you will need to change WowzaStreamingEngine folder permissions for start Wowza by Eclipse (for Mac/linux)